# Count and display most recent blog posts in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, dynamic-html

What is the javascript in order to only display posts 3 & 4 in order???
Also I need it be dynamic so if I put a 5th post it will only display 4th and 5th posts... I was thinking about something like a date function or a simple incrementor but can't seem to figure it out. I'm new to javascript and have been trying different things but no avail... Thanks in advance...

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="posts-div">
    <h1 class="post-title">post4</h1>
    <p class="post">post4</p>
</div>

<div id="posts-div">
    <h1 class="post-title">post3</h1>
    <p class="post">post3</p>
</div>

<div id="posts-div">
    <h1 class="post-title">post2</h1>
    <p class="post">post2</p>
</div>

<div id="posts-div">
    <h1 class="post-title">post1</h1>
    <p class="post">post1</p>
</div>

<script>
// ???
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to change your code: you're listing different elements with the same id, which is invalid. You probably want to use a class instead.

Comment: `be dynamic so if I put a 5th post` : put it were ?, can you put any code you tried before ? are you using JQuery or it's pure js ?

Comment: Also, it might be a good idea if you organise your divs inside another div, this time identified with an id. Then you can use appendChild() to add new posts and you can use a MutationObserver to detect any changes in the container and the child divs. But then, why should you complicate your life with a MutationObserver at all, when you can manage which elements are visible every time you add a post?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need script for that. You can do it with CSS.. I have changed your html little bit (made posts-div class in html).

```css
.posts-div{
  display:none;
}
.posts-div:nth-child(-n+2) {
   display:block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="posts-div">
      <h1 class="post-title">post5</h1>
      <p class="post">post5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="posts-div">
      <h1 class="post-title">post4</h1>
      <p class="post">post4</p>
  </div>

  <div class="posts-div">
      <h1 class="post-title">post3</h1>
      <p class="post">post3</p>
  </div>

  <div class="posts-div">
      <h1 class="post-title">post2</h1>
      <p class="post">post2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="posts-div">
      <h1 class="post-title">post1</h1>
      <p class="post">post1</p>
  </div>

<script>
// ???
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can test it on JSfiddle as well.. https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/b5eL3ykx/6/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.posts-div:gt(1)').hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="posts-div">
    <h1 class="post-title">post4</h1>
    <p class="post">post4</p>
</div>

<div class="posts-div">
    <h1 class="post-title">post3</h1>
    <p class="post">post3</p>
</div>

<div class="posts-div">
    <h1 class="post-title">post2</h1>
    <p class="post">post2</p>
</div>

<div class="posts-div">
    <h1 class="post-title">post1</h1>
    <p class="post">post1</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var allPosts = document.querySelectorAll(".posts-div");
    // This is the number of posts you want displayed
    var numberOfPostsToShow = 2;

    for (var i = 0; i < allPosts.length; i++) {

       if(i > numberOfPostsToShow - 1) {
           allPosts[i].style.display = "none";
       }

    }
});
</script>
```

This way you will choose how many posts you want to be shown with the **numberOfPostsToShow** variable.

Let me know if this worked. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The way I interpreted your question, you need a way to:

- show only the first n elements;
- add new elements to the top of the list of posts, dynamically;
- when you add them, update the visible elements.

Assuming a slightly modified version of your code, which corrects the id/class issue and adds a container for all the posts (this time with a proper id):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <div id="posts-container">
        <div class="posts-div">
            <h1 class="post-title">post4</h1>
            <p class="post">post4</p>
        </div>

        <div class="posts-div">
            <h1 class="post-title">post3</h1>
            <p class="post">post3</p>
        </div>

        <div class="posts-div">
            <h1 class="post-title">post2</h1>
            <p class="post">post2</p>
        </div>

        <div class="posts-div">
            <h1 class="post-title">post1</h1>
            <p class="post">post1</p>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
// ???
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this code will do the trick and manage both the addition and the updates to the visibility of the posts:

```
function showOnly(visible, query){
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(query);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        if (i < visible - 1){
            elements[i].style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            elements[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}

function publishPost(element, visible){
    showOnly(visible, '#posts-container .posts-div')
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#posts-container .posts-div');
    element.style.display = 'block';
    if (elements.length > 0) {
        document.querySelector('#posts-container').insertBefore(element, elements[0]);
    } else {
        document.querySelector('#posts-container').appendChild(element);
    }
}
```

The showOnly function (to be called with the number of elements to be shown and the string that identifies the elements with querySelectorAll) will only make visible the first n elements identified by the string. You can use it independently of the rest of the code if needed.

The publishPost function, on the other hand, is strictly dependent on the modified html above (to use it elsewhere you will need to adjust the strings fed to querySelector and querySelectorAll). It takes the element to be published as the first argument, the number of elements that need to be visible as the second. Then it updates the list of posts prepending the new one to it, and it also updates which posts are visible.

This is a code sample that uses it:

```
var elDiv = document.createElement('div');
var elH1 = document.createElement('h1');
var elP = document.createElement('p');
elDiv.classList = 'posts-div';
elH1.classList = 'post-title';
elP.classList = 'post';
elH1.innerText = 'some title';
elP.innerText = 'some text for the post';
elDiv.appendChild(elH1).appendChild(elP);
publishPost(elDiv, 2);
```

## showOnly

This function starts by getting a list of the elements whose visibility must be managed:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(query);
```

then it loops through the list and examines each element:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
```

if it has to be visible, it sets the style.display property to 'block':

```
if (i < visible){
    elements[i].style.display = 'block';
```

otherwise it sets it to 'hidden':

```
else {
    elements[i].style.display = 'none';
```

## publishPost

This function starts by showing only n-1 elements (because it will need to add a new, visible element to the top of the list):

```
showOnly(visible - 1, '#posts-container .posts-div')
```

then it retrieve the current posts:

```
var elements = document.querySelector('#posts-container .posts-div');
```

it makes the new element visible:

```
element.style.display = 'block';
```

finally, it adds the element to the top of the list (the different syntax depends on wether the list is empty):

```
if (elements.length > 0) {
    document.querySelector('#posts-container').insertBefore(element, elements[0]);
} else {
    document.querySelector('#posts-container').appendChild(element);
}
```